# Find not deployed commits in git history

Tags: git

When we are planing a next release, we build the release notes by looking at commits which are not included in the last release. Normally we use gitk and a trained eye to detect such commits. But now, since the number of commits and branches are increasing, it gets harder and harder to see those.

Is there a command which prints all commits under HEAD but not a specific tag? To make this more clear I added this over simplified example.

```
                    F <- develop | HEAD
                    | \ 
                    D E
                    | |
last_release_tag -> B C
                    |/
                    A
```

The expected output would be: C E D F (The order is not important.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a range of commits including everything up to HEAD, but excluding things up to the last release tag. You might use:

```
git log last_release_tag..HEAD
```

which is equivalent to:

```
git log ^last_release_tag HEAD
```

See "SPECIFYING RANGES" in [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for more detail. In the second form you can use more than one `^last_release_tag` if you need to exclude multiple tags (this might be necessary if e.g. version C was also released).

You might also want to investigate options like `--oneline` or the `--pretty` formats to customise the output, depending on how you want your release notes to look. More detail can be found under "PRETTY FORMATS" in [git-log(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Comment: I never would have guest that it is that easy. Thank you, this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

gitk is just a graphical layer on top of the standard Git tools. In your example,

```
git log last_release_tag..F
```

would list information about the commits you want. The command should be interpreted as "commits reachable by F except those reachable by the commit that last_release_tag points to". There are numerous formatting options if the default output format doesn't suit your needs, see [git-log(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html). For details on how revision ranges can be specified see [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

For scripting purposes where you only want the SHA-1s of the commits, use the `git rev-list` plumbing command.

Comment: Probably should be either `last_release_tag..HEAD` or `^last_release_tag HEAD`. As it is now, it'll pretty much list everything that's an ancestor of either `last_release_tag` or `F`.

Answer (score 0):

A bash script should do the job:

```
for commit in `git log --pretty=format:"%H" START_COMMIT..HEAD; do
  # Is there a tag which points to this commit ?
  tag=`git tag -l --points-at $commit`; 
  # Test if not the specific tag
  if test "$tag" != "specific_tag"; then 
    # You can use any git command on the commit here
    echo $commit;
  fi ; 
done
```